# How to Split the string in the same line?

Tags: sql, netsuite

I have selected the cases that are error (error_cash_sales) in processing from the cash_sales table.
However, the results would show the whole error cash sales which successful and error items are shown.

command I have typed:

```
SELECT error_cash_sales
FROM cash_sales
WHERE error_satus = 'yes' ;
```

Results it will generate:

| Error_cash_sales |
| --- |
| "item":108,"itemid":"CCC001123","itemtype":"InvtPart"},"item":4533,"itemid":"ABC123","itemtype":"InvtPart"},{"item":12584,"itemid":"ABC012584","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":{"success":0,"message":"inadequate component quantity on hand: 803"},"error":"Please configure the inventory detail for this line."},{"item":5034,"itemid":"QWE12345","itemtype":"InvtPart"},{"item":13573,"itemid":"ERT013573","itemtype":"InvtPart"},"item":3452,"itemid":"KASDKAJ123","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":{"success":0,"message":"inadequate component quantity on hand: 1841"},"error":"Please configure the inventory detail for this line."},"item":3456,"itemid":"QWUI1234","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":"success":1,"lotnumber":"20220415","assemblyId":1965818}},{"item":350,"itemid":"KSAF1234804","itemtype":"InvtPart"},{"item":112,"itemid":"QWERTTT123","itemtype":"InvtPart"},"item":13943,"itemid":"QQ1234","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":{"success":1,"lotnumber":"20220415","assemblyId":1965820}} |

what I want to show is different the line would be split according to the "item" which can let me check item with error easily:
(it can be within one row/separated into several rows)

| Error_cash_sales |
| --- |
| {"item":108,"itemid":"CCC001123","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":4533,"itemid":"ABC123","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":12584,"itemid":"ABC012584","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":"success":0,"message":"inadequate component quantity on hand: 803"},"error":"Please configure the inventory detail for this line."}, |
| {"item":5034,"itemid":"QWE12345","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":13573,"itemid":"ERT013573","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":3452,"itemid":"KASDKAJ123","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":"success":0,"message":"inadequate component quantity on hand: 1841"},"error":"Please configure the inventory detail for this line."}, |
| {"item":3456,"itemid":"QWUI1234","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":"success":1,"lotnumber":"20220415","assemblyId":1965818}}, |
| {"item":350,"itemid":"KSAF1234804","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":112,"itemid":"QWERTTT123","itemtype":"InvtPart"}, |
| {"item":13943,"itemid":"QQ1234","itemtype":"Assembly","assemblyInfo":"success":1,"lotnumber":"20220415","assemblyId":1965820}} |

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (mysql, presto, t-sql, etc.)

Comment: I am working on NetSuite that a tool called "SuiteQL Query Tool".